# Appropriate distance measures

Tags: dataset, image-processing, similarities

I am working with hyperspectral image data in R, so I have subset an image to a region of 5000 pixels, each containing a vector 254 bands in length.

I would like to cluster this data in order to try and map regions with similar surface composition.

Due to differences in surface reflectance, if I plot two pixels, where for example: x=1:254, y=0:1 (reflectance)

They may have very similar shape (values across all bands) but be vertically offset from one another due to the overall reflectance of the surface.

For my region I have a mean spectrum, and each pixel contains a vector of 254 residual values. I can't use Euclidean distance to compare vectors, because it will change depending on the overall reflectance, so I'm not sure if there's a more appropriate measure to use that will give me a better comparison.

- This question is also posted at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139591/appropriate-histogram-comparison-distance-measure, where it was suggested that the earth-mover distance may be a good one to try. If I do use this, then am I bringing the spectra into alignment by subtracting or adding the EM distance to one vector? If this is the case, then I lose the small differences between them?

Essentially, I would like to compare the differences in reflectance of each band to the mean, regardless of its overall reflectance offset.

Additionally, and here is the embarrassing part: the original data (5000 observations for each band) has a distribution that is very slightly skewed right, and in some cases slightly bimodal. The mean spectrum may not even be an appropriate measure for this entire exercise, but I'm not sure what to do in this case.